# Props not being displayed in new route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to learn React Native but it has been tougher than I thought. I can't create a simple "master-detail" app (and I couldn't find a good, simple tutorial explaining how to do it either).

I've managed to display a list of categories. After clicking one, it should display the category name + the list of items from this:

```
const data = [{
  "category": "Fruits",
  "items": [{
    "name": "Apple",
    "icon": "apple.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Orange",
    "icon": "orange.png"
  }]
}, {
  "category": "Vegetables",
  "items": [{
    "name": "Lettuce",
    "icon": "lettuce.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Mustard",
    "icon": "mustard.png"
  }]
}];
```

On my main class, I managed to display a list of categories:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData) => 
  <Text onPress={this.onPressItem.bind(this, rowData.category)}>
    {rowData.category}
  </Text>}
/>
```

In my `onPressItem` I have the following:

```
onPressItem(category) {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'DetailView',
    component: DetailView,
    passProps: {
      category 
    }
  });
}
```

In my detail view, the `category` name is not being displayed:

```
class DetailView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Text>Category: { this.props.category }</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.props.navigator.pop() }>
            <Text>GO Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can help me with this. It's probably something silly I'm doing wrong. Creating this simple thing can't be that hard. :/

[Full code](https://rnplay.org/apps/zEeMzA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I was making a mistake when rendering the view:

```
return React.createElement(
  route.component,
  { navigator },
  {...route.passProps}
);
```

The right way is:

```
return React.createElement(
  route.component,
  { navigator, ...route.passProps }
);
```

Thanks to [mehcode](https://github.com/mehcode/) for helping me out.